# python where to place or how to find resources in code or test (e.g. env file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I just started python programming. I have a FastApi project with this structure:

```
/
  /app
   /router
   /config
      config.py -- use pydantic-settings
      dev-default.env -- contains default settings
  /tests
    /unit
      /resources
        test.json
    /integration 

README.md
```

I put the `dev-default.env` just besides `config.py` that loads it - because it works in linux and windows (at least running the app).

If i run a test that uses settings the env file is searched relative to test and not relative to `config.py` anymore.

In one of my tests i use this to get path of resource - relative to this test:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                       'resources',
                       'test.json')) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

For me both ways feel wrong - and are not very stable to change

- putting resources beside the file that uses them (depends on "current folder" - in test different)
- loading resources relative to file path (move file around or resource breaks it)

And both ways are not stable: e.g.running pytest will not load the env file (as long as i do not copy the env file to folder where tests runs)

So my question is: What is a good practice here or the way to go in python to handle and access resources.
I would like to have a path or make one available that works from everywhere and works in Linux and Windows. something like this:

```
path = resource("env/dev-default.env")
path = resource("testfiles/test.json")

or 

path = f"{approot}/env/dev-default.env"
```

Is there a library or pattern to achieve this? i am also fine if i have to apply a certain folder structure (as for example in Java)